# TextEditor development in C# .net 2.0

Tags: .net, windows, forms, c#-2.0

I'm novice developer. I'm trying to imitate the Windows notepad features. I'm using Windows forms application and language is C#.

My questions are:

1. What are the design considerations for text editor development?
2. How do I implement the cut and copy functionality without using the framework given `textbox.Cut` or `textbox.Copy`?
3. I've written code for opening the file and I'm searching a way to store the data while user is typing. Do I need to use some data structure? If so, please guide me on how to do that.
4. Here is the code I've written to open a new file. Is there a way to improve this? When I open a new file, the pointer will not appear at all until I press the tab.

   ```
   TextBox txt = new TextBox();
   txt.Multiline = true;
   txt.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;        
   panel1.Controls.Add(txt);
   panel1.Focus();
   ```
5. Is it necessary to use the graphics in Notepad? If so, please help me with a resolution.

Comment: Your questions are too abstract. Please, clarify whether you have any problems you can't solve.

Comment: In short when you do a cut action how to determine the start and end position of the string and where to move it like to buffer or to clipboard.

Comment: Feel free to use MSDN to answer these questions by yourself. TextBox has a property "SelectionStart": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart.aspx Then, regarding the clipboard: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard.aspx Your questions doesn't worth asking them here.

Comment: @mason Could you please elaborate, what was wrong with my edit?

Comment: @defaultlocale A trivial edit to a 3 year old question.

Comment: @mason well, my main goal was to fix tags. Currently they are quite meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

> 1> What are the design considerations to be done for texteditor
>   development.

- Decide whether you want to edit a single document only, or construct an MDI (multiple document interface).
- Decide on a feature set; for example, tabstop size, line ending conversion, encoding selection, or even spellcheck.

> 2> How to implement the Cut and copy functionality without using the
>   framework given textbox.Cut or textbox.Copy.

You need to read about `System.Windows.Clipboard`. Note that this requires .NET 3.5.

> 3> I've written code for opening the file and I'm searching a way to
>   store the data while user is typing, means do I need to use some data
>   structure or something else. If yes please guide me on how to do that.

The simplest way to do this is to let the text control itself store the data for you, in its Text property. You might not need to store the text yourself.

> 4> Here is the code I've written to open a new file. Is there a way to
>   improve this, as when i open new file, pointer will not appear at all until i press the tab.

Instead of focusing to the panel, try focusing to the text box itself.

> 5> is it necessary to use the graphics in notepad. if yes please help me with a resolution.

You can construct a fully functional text editor without ever having to touch custom graphics or user-drawn controls.